# Margin of header makes "a" tag unclickable

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and trying to build responsive restaurant website. Everything works perfectly except on mobile phones sometimes links do not work. But there is not any problem with top 2 links. I checked the website and saw that the top Margin of header is in front of those menu links. In my opinion that is causing the problem. How can I make those links to appear in front of margin of another element so it can be clickable? Here is how it looks. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b51bb.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Where is you code? Reproducible example? Please familiarize yourself with how to ask questions on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual html & css for the overlapping element and the nav it is difficult to tell, but I think you might have a `z-index` issue here, so try to set the following styles on the nav-wrapper element:

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; /* or higher if the content is wrapped in a container with higher z-index */
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad my blind guess helped =)...please consider accepting the answer as a solution in that case, makes it easier to scan for "unanswered" questions!

Comment: Sorry but how to do it? I am new to stack overflow

Comment: No problem, welcome =)! As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept it as an answer.